# Mysql-query - find all rows where ID is divisible by 4

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a query that returns all rows where ID (auto increment integer) is divisible by 4?

select * from mydatabase where id is divisble by 4 oder by id asc.

for instance i would like to get the rows with id 4, 8, 12, and so on..

Edit:

just as additional information for completeness, what if I would need the rows 1, 5, 9 etc?

Comment: I have done changes in my ans

Answer (score 12, accepted):

here % do if your id divide by 4 and it give without reminder means equal to 0 then it will give you a result.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id % 4) = 0;
```

if you need  1,5,9 then you need to do `id-1%4`
it is means you need 4+1=5,8+1=9 so you need to do `((id-1)%4` 
remember do not forget to put (id-1) like this. because without it it will follow math rule and do first 1%4

```
SELECT * FROM user_rules where ((id-1) % 4)=0 limit 0,4
```

Comment: thanks, will accpet the answer in 10 minutes as soon as the timer is up.

Comment: just as additional information for completeness, what if I would need the rows 1, 5, 9 etc? (being the first four, then the next four and so on...)

Comment: if some one question it i will ans

Comment: I added it on the main question

Comment: It will be a better answer if you will explain the your answer!

Comment: @knowledge.... thank you! the second part you posted does select row 5, 9 etc.. but its not selecting row 1.. am i right on that? accepted your answer

Comment: I am getting the 1

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the bitwise operator `&` because 4 is a power of 2.

You can replace `% 4` with `& (4 - 1)` making it `& 3`

Using in a query.

**Query**

```
SELECT
 *
FROM 
 [table] 
WHERE
 (id & 3) = 0
```

Comment: @knowledge.... Query should work should return 4,8,12,16.... check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8b55e/1 or http://rextester.com/YFMDE21718

Answer (score 1):

This seems already too easy...

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id % 4 = 0
```